# DbContext type is not defined

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-6.1

Working with EF 6.1. I've created two table class files:

```
Public Class Student

    Public Property StudentID() As Integer
    Public Property StudentName() As String
    Public Property DateOfBirth() As DateTime

End Class

Public Class Standard

    Public Property StandardID() As Integer
    Public Property StandardName() As String

End Class
```

Also created one DbContext file (SchoolContext.vb):

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Namespace TestDataAccess

    Public Class SchoolContext
        Inherits DbContext

        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbConnString").ConnectionString)
        End Sub

        Private _Students As DbSet(Of Student)

        Private _Standards As DbSet(Of Standard)

    End Class

End Namespace
```

In my test page, I'm making reference to the DbContext file by using the following:

```
Dim context As SchoolContext = New SchoolContext
```

but it keeps giving the error "Type 'SchoolContext' is not defined." Even tried importing the namespace 'TestDataAccess' but still received the error. I did install EF into my project via NuGet, and it show in my packages.config file, so I know that's not the issue.

```
<package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: It seems like you are missing an import statement in your test page. If you right click on red squiggle where SchoolContext's type is, does it offer an option to Resolve by including a namespace?

Comment: Travis, no the red squiggle just wants me to change SchoolContext to HttpContext. Even if I import my DbContext namespace mainly, even it is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

I am nog very familiare with vb, but what is the scope of your DbContext.
Shouldn't _standards and _studente be public instead of private?

Comment: Rik, yes good eye. I forgot to fix that code after reduced my property statements down to a single line. That doesn't resolve my type is not defined error though unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You need the EntityFramework.dll reference (and not System.Data.Entity).

Comment: And yes make _standards and _students as public as Rik suggested

Comment: Hasta, I can see the EntityFramework.dll in my reference list under References in my Solution Explorer. As long as I can see it there, I should be good, correct? Or is there another location I should be checking?

Comment: Hi, That's odd. I think you might want to delete that reference and reinstall it again and  hope it works. Other than that I have no suggestions Apologies mate